# Plan guide validation with fn_validate_plan_guide gives false positives

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, plan-guides

When validating a plan guide for a piece of SQL in a stored procedure that references a temporary table named "#test" the function fn_validate_plan_guide returns the error: Invalid object name '#test'.

But the the plan guide still pushes the query hint into the SQL and the desired execution is achieved.

Does this highlight a problem with the fn_validate_plan_guide function?

The script below recreates the problem.

```
--Enable the actual execution plan before running the query so the plans can be compared

USE [msdb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #test 
    (
        ID INT
    )

    INSERT INTO #test
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY job_id) 
    FROM dbo.sysjobs

    SELECT * 
    FROM #test t
    JOIN #test t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID

    DROP TABLE #Test 
END
GO

--Execution before the plan guide is created will have a hash join in the second batch
EXEC msdb.dbo.test
GO

--Create the plan guide
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide 'test',
'   SELECT * 
    FROM #test t
    JOIN #test t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID', 
'OBJECT', 'dbo.test', NULL, 'OPTION (MERGE JOIN)'
GO

--Validate the plan guide. This returns the error "Invalid object name '#test'."
SELECT 
    plan_guide_id, msgnum, severity, state, message, 
    name, create_date, is_disabled, query_text, scope_type_desc, scope_batch, parameters, hints
FROM sys.plan_guides
CROSS APPLY fn_validate_plan_guide(plan_guide_id);
GO

--Execution after the plan guide is created will have a merge join in the second batch
EXEC msdb.dbo.test
GO

EXEC sp_control_plan_guide 'DISABLE', 'test'
GO

--Execution after the plan guide is disabled will go back to having a hash join in the second batch
EXEC msdb.dbo.test
GO

EXEC sp_control_plan_guide 'ENABLE', 'test'
GO

--Execution after the plan guide is re-enabled will go back to having a merge join in the second batch
EXEC msdb.dbo.test
GO

--Clean up
EXEC sp_control_plan_guide 'DROP', 'test'
GO

DROP PROCEDURE test
GO
```

Is this function giving errors that are false positives or are these just warnings that the plan guide may fail or is it something else I haven't thought of?

I have created a Connect item [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1981369) with the text above but am yet to have a response.

Comment: No function will ever replace true validation (as in testing that running the actual query yields the plan you desire). I've actually never used that function to test anything.

Comment: Yep I agree. I wont be using it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a limitation of *sys.fn_validate_plan_guide* that can cause a false negative (not a false positive).

The server attempts to compile just the statement in the plan guide, not the whole batch (stored procedure in this case). The request fails because the temporary table definition is not part of the compilation.

I could not reproduce the same issue with a table variable on:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU2) (KB3137746) - 11.0.6523.0 (X64) 
    Mar  2 2016 21:29:16 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 10586: )
```

The plan validation and guide application worked correctly.

#### Workarounds

Requesting an estimated plan for a call to the procedure succeeds, with the resulting batch plan showing the guided plan, with the properties of the statement root node showing the correct *PlanGuideDB* and *PlanGuideName* properties in SSMS:

[image: Estimated plan]

An alternative is to create the temporary table (copied from the procedure definition) on the session that calls *sys.fn_validate_plan_guide*.

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
(
    ID INT
);

-- Succeeds
SELECT 
    PG.plan_guide_id,
    PG.name,
    PG.scope_type_desc,
    PG.hints,
    FVPG.msgnum,
    FVPG.severity,
    FVPG.[state],
    FVPG.[message]
FROM sys.plan_guides AS PG
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_validate_plan_guide(PG.plan_guide_id) AS FVPG;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

Either of these can be used to validate the negative result from *sys.fn_validate_plan_guide* when the error refers to a missing #object.